# How to get inv of special type of Matrix with same elements in each column

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `B`, as shown below. How can we get `inv(B)` using MATLAB?

```
B =[ 1.7511, 0.1891, -1.3523;
     1.7511, 0.1891, -1.3523;
     1.7511, 0.1891, -1.3523 ];
```

Comment: Have you tried `inv(B)`?

Comment: Yes and the result was 3*3 matrix of INF

Comment: That should tell you something about `B`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A matrix is [invertible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix), if the columns are linearly independent. This means that a column `a` can not be expressed in function of columns `b` and `c`, e.g. by `a = 2*b+c`. In your case, all columns are identical, i.e. `a = b = c`, so they are not linearly independent, and your matrix is **not invertible**.

Answer (score 5):

By typing  `inv(B)`. This is the exact command for the inverse.

Note that the inverse in this case does not exist (see [@hdaberts's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414879/5211833) for that), which is why you get the following warning:

> Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.

That already tells you MATLAB simply can't calculate the inverse.

You'll want more often to use `\` though, as this chooses the optimal strategy for calculating problems of the type Ax=c, where x is unknown. `x=A\c` would be the syntax in that case.

From the [documentation on `inv`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inv.html):

> `Y = inv(X)` returns the inverse of the square matrix `X`. A warning message is printed if `X` is badly scaled or nearly singular.
>
> In practice, it is seldom necessary to form the explicit inverse of a matrix. A frequent misuse of `inv` arises when solving the system of linear equations `Ax = b`. One way to solve this is with `x = inv(A)*b`. A better way, from both an execution time and numerical accuracy standpoint, is to use the matrix division operator `x = A\b`. This produces the solution using Gaussian elimination, without forming the inverse. See [`mldivide` (`\`)](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mldivide.html) for further information.