# MATLAB - Solving multiple linear systems where A (the matrix to be inverted) is the same

Tags: matlab

I have the following code excerpt:

```
%suppose A is a 40000 by 40000 matrix
phi = zeros(40000,1);  
for t = 1:360
      phivec = -phi;
      phi = full(A\sparse(phivec));
end
```

For each t, I solve the system A*x = phivec. For t=1, phivec is given. For t>1, phivec comes from the phivec at t-1. Is there a way to speed up the process, since A is the same for each t. I did try to invert A before the loop starts and do a matrix multiplication, but since A is huge (40000*40000), it's taking a lot of memory. Is there a way to invert A for just once to save time?

Comment: To invert it once, simply use `inv`. Do see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34414767/5211833) on why that's generally not recommended though. I'm not sure how it'd work out in this particular case in terms of speed due to the loop, you'll want to test that. Keep track of the precision along the way, as `inv` is notoriously bad at that.

Comment: @Adriaan I did try that, but eventually I would have to do a multiplication to get what I want, since I'm trying to get x = A\phivec. When I did inv(A)*phivec, the script takes up a lot of memory, since A is too big. Is there a way to get around that?

Comment: Get the `inv(A)` outside the loop, although that won't solve your memory problem. If you do `tmp = inv(A); for t = 1:360; phivec = -phi;phi = tmp*phivec;end` it should improve time wise, as you only calculate the inverse once. However, it indeed consumes a stupendous amount of memory to invert a matrix fully, hence it's recommended to use `mldivide` usually. Try it with the inversion out of the loop and see whether it suits your purposes.

Comment: @Adriaan That's what I tried exactly, but it occupies a lot of memory and makes my machine really slow. I also tried mldivide with an identity matrix, but the same result occurred: too much memory occupied.

Comment: Then you have two options left as far as I can see: either go with the code you have and use the optimised way of solving linear algebra problems, the backslash, or buy more RAM and try again. I'm not familiar enough with this topic to give you anything else to go on, sorry.